# Haskell Hamming numbers, works but shows duplicates

Tags: haskell, hamming-numbers, smooth-numbers

I am trying to generate hamming numbers in haskell, the problem is I get duplicate #'s in my output list and I cannot figure out why exactly. Should I just create a remove duplicates function or am I just missing something simple?

Also in the function hamming I would like to make sure the size of the input list is exactly 3, how do I find the size of a list so I can do the comparison?

```
{- Merge lists x&y of possibly infinite lengths -}
merge [] [] = []
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xs ys = min x y : if x < y then merge (tail xs) ys
                             else merge xs (tail ys)
    where x = head xs
          y = head ys

{- multiply each element in y by x -}
times x [] = []
times x y = x * (head y) : times x (tail y)

{- find the hamming numbers of the input primes list -}
ham [] = []
ham x = 1 : merge (times (head x) (ham x))
             (merge (times (x !! 1) (ham x)) (times (last x) (ham x)))

{- returns x hamming #'s based on y primes of size 3 -}
hamming x [] = []
hamming x y = take x (ham y) 
{- hamming x y = if "y.size = 3" then take x (ham y) 
                                 else "Must supply 3 primes in input list" -}
```

Comment: coincidentally, `nodups xs = map head (Data.List.group xs)` for ordered non-decreasing lists.

Answer (score 2):

You get duplicates because many of the hamming numbers are multiples of several of the base numbers, and you don't remove duplicates in your `merge` function. For example, for the classical `2, 3, 5` Hamming numbers, you obtain 6 as `2 * 3` as well as `3 * 2`.

You could of course create a duplicate removal function. Since the list you create is sorted, that wouldn't even be very inefficient. Or you could remove the duplicates in the merge function.

> how do I find the size of a list so I can do the comparison?

You can obtain the length of a list using the `length` function that is available from the `Prelude`, but let me warn you right now that calling `length` should only be done if the length is really required, since `length` has to traverse the entire list to calculate its length. If the list happens to be long, that takes a lot of time, and may cause huge memory usage if the list is referenced elsewhere so that it cannot be garbage-collected. If the list is even infinite, evaluating its length will of course never terminate.

What you want to do can also be achieved by pattern-matching,

```
ham [a, b, c] = list
  where
    list = 1 : merge (map (a*) list) (merge (map (b*) list) (map (c*) list))
ham _ = []
```

You could also use a guard with a `length` check

```
hamming x y
    | length y == 3 = take x (ham y)
    | otherwise     = []
```

to make sure that your input list has exactly three elements, but you will regret that if you call `hamming 10 [1 .. ]`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `List` module, Haskell has a duplicate remover called `nub`.  Here it is on hoogle: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nub. This is O(n^2) though, so you might be better off changing `merge`.  But it may be worthwhile to first use a slow solution already written for you, before optimizing.

I suspect that you are trying to learn Haskell with this little exercise, but here's another way to write out the hamming numbers (no duplicates, but not in order) using *the List monad*:

```
uglyNumbers = do { n <- [0..] 
                 ; k <- [0..n] 
                 ; j <- [0..n-k] 
                 ; return $ (2^(n-k-j))*(3^j)*(5^k) }
```

This makes a lazy, infinite list of hamming numbers.  You can equivalently write this using a *list comprehension*:

```
uglyNumbers' = [(2^(n-k-j))*(3^j)*(5^k) | n <- [0..], k <- [0..n], j <- [0..n-k]]
```